# Which festivals did these fasts correspond with in Zechariah 8:19?

Tags: law, zechariah, niv

Zechariah 8:19 NIV

19 This is what the Lord Almighty says: “***The fasts of the fourth, fifth, seventh and tenth months*** will become joyful and glad occasions and happy festivals for Judah. Therefore love truth and peace.”

The fasts mentioned above corresponded with which festivals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original establishment of the Israelite covenant, there were three festivals or "feasts" that Israel was commanded to celebrate.

> Ex 23:14 - **Three times a year** you are to celebrate a feast to Me.
>
> Ex 23:17 - **Three times a year** all your males are to appear before the
> Lord GOD.
>
> Ex 34:23  - **Three times a year** all your males are to appear before the
> Lord GOD
>
> Deut 16:16 - **Three times a year** all your men are to
> appear before the LORD your God

These three festivals were as follows:

- Passover & unleavened bread in the 1st month
- Pentecost in the 3rd month
- Trumpets, Atonement and tabernacles in the 7th month

These were all celebrations and variously called festivals or feasts.  Ex 23:14-19; Ex 34, Lev 23, Deut 16:1-16.

However, as a result of various events in Israel's history, others were added such as Purim, Hanukkah, etc.

In the case of Zech 8:19 (see also Zech 7:3, 5), the occasions are specifically listed as "fasts" that commemorate a very sorrowful event.  These were probably:

- 4th month (Tammuz) - the capture of Jerusalem, see 2 Kings 25:1-9, Jer 39:2, 3, 52:6, 7, 12-16.
- 5th month (Ab) - the destruction of Jerusalem, see 2 Kings 25:1-9, Jer 52:12-16.
- 7th month (Tishri) - possibly the murder of Gedaliah(?) and the flight to Egypt, see 2 Kings 25:22-26, Jer 41:1, 2, 52:4, Zech 7:5)
- 10th month (Tebeth) - possibly Nebuchadnezzar's start of the siege of Jerusalem, see 2 Kings 25:1, 2, Jer 39:1, 52:4.

Matthew Poole reaches a similar conclusion:

> The fast of the fourth month; wherein the city was taken by the
> Babylonians, who on the ninth day of this month broke into the city,
> Jeremiah 52:6,7.
>
> Of the fifth; of which on the tenth day the temple was burnt.
>
> Of the seventh; wherein Gedaliah was killed, Jeremiah 41:1.
>
> Of the tenth; on the tenth day whereof the king of Babylon’s army sat
> down before the city and besieged it.

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted a fine answer. +1.

Answer (score 1):

According to Rabbi Kimchi's commentary:

> “The fast of the fourth month.”—This is **Tammuz** in which they fasted in captivity, on the 17th of the month, the day on which a
> breach was effected in the city.
>
> “The fast of the fifth month.”—This
> is **Av**, in which they fasted on the 9th day.
>
> “The fast of the seventh
> month.”—This is the fast of **Gedaliah**, as we interpreted above.
>
> “The fast of the tenth month.”—This is the tenth of **Tevath**, on which day
> the King of Babylon invested Jerusalem.
> Kimchi, D. (1837). Rabbi David Kimchi’s Commentary upon the Prophecies of Zechariah. (A. M’Caul, Trans.) (pp. 79–80). London: James Duncan.

Note that these are all periods of fasting/mourning and are covered in 2 Kings 25 but the exact date that the walls were breached is not mentioned in 2 Kings but is mentioned in Jeremiah.

### Tevath

This commemorates the start of the seige of Jerusalem by the Babylonians and is recorded in 2 Ki 25.1-7:

> It happened that in the ninth year of his reign, in the **tenth month,
> on the tenth of the month**, Nebuchadnezzar the king of Babylon came, he
> and all his army, against Jerusalem. He encamped against it and built
> siege works against it all around. So the city came under siege until
> the eleventh year of King Zedekiah. In the ninth month, the famine
> became severe in the city, and there was no food for the people of the
> land. Then the city was breached, and all of the men of war entered by
> night by way of the gate between the wall which was by the garden of
> the king, and the Chaldeans were against the city all around, so he
> left by the way of the Arabah. But the army of the Chaldeans pursued
> the king, and they overtook him in the Arabah of Jericho, and all of
> his army scattered from him. So they captured the king and brought him
> up to the king of Babylon at Riblah, and they passed sentence on him.
> They slaughtered the sons of Zedekiah before his eyes; then they
> blinded the eyes of Zedekiah and bound him in bronze fetters and
> brought him to Babylon. (LEB)

### Tammuz

The walls breached. Jer 52.5-7:

> So the city came under siege until the eleventh year of King Zedekiah.
> **In the fourth month, on the ninth day of the month**, the famine in the city became severe and there was no food for the people of the
> land. Then the city was breached, and all the soldiers fled and went
> out from the city by night by the way of the gate between the two
> walls that are at the garden of the king, though the Chaldeans were
> all around the city. And they went in the direction of the Jordan
> Valley. (LEB)

### Av

The Temple is burned.

This is the greatest day of calamity for Israel. The wikipedia article lists some of the many disasters that happened on that day, including [the destruction of both temples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tisha_B%27Av) (on the same day).

A Biblical reference is 2 Ki 25.8-12

> In the **fifth month**, on the **seventh of the month**, that is, the
> nineteenth year of King Nebuchadnezzar the king of Babylon,
> Nebuzaradan, a commander of the imperial guard, a servant of the king
> of Babylon, came to Jerusalem. He burned the temple of Yahweh, the
> palace of the king, and all of the houses of Jerusalem; every large
> house he burned with fire. And all the army of the Chaldeans who were
> with the commander of the imperial guard tore down the walls of
> Jerusalem all around. The remainder of the people left in the city,
> the deserters who had deserted to the king of Babylon, and the
> remainder of the multitude, Nebuzaradan the commander of the imperial
> guard deported. But the poor of the land the commander of the imperial
> guard left for the vineyards and for tilling.

### Gedaliah

The assassination of Gedaliah.

This is significant because the nobility had been deported and the people who stayed behind under occupation lived in fear. But Gedaliah was a prominent jew and was appointed governor of Judea, and this gave the people who left behind some assurance. Thus his assassination resulted in terror and people fled into Egypt and ended up being cut off from the promise.

Here is the NAC commentary:

> Nebuchadnezzar appoints Gedaliah to govern what remains of Jerusalem.
> Cogan and Tadmor note that “Gedaliah was of a prominent Jerusalem
> family. His grandfather was the scribe during the reign of Josiah (2
> Kgs 22:3), and his father was a member of the mission sent to Huldah …
> and later intervened to save Jeremiah from threatening the prophet’s
> life (Jer 26:24).” He seems to be an honorable, trusting person
> despite his willingness to serve Babylon (cf. Jer 40:7–16). His
> counsel to the people seems sound enough. If they settle down and make
> no trouble, all will be well. After all, Jeremiah has already
> predicted a seventy-year exile, beginning with 605 B.C. (cf. Jer
> 29:10), so why fight now?
> House, P. R. (1995). 1, 2 Kings (Vol. 8, p. 399). Nashville: Broadman & Holman Publishers.

The Feast of Gedaliah occurs the day after Rosh Hashanah and remembers the events of 2 Kings 25.25-26:

> But it happened in the **seventh month** that Ishmael the son of Nethaniah
> the son of Elishama from the offspring of the kingship came, and ten
> men with him, and they struck down Gedaliah so that he died with the
> Judeans and with the Chaldeans who were with him at Mizpah. **Then all
> the people, from youngest to oldest, and the commanders of the troops,
> went to Egypt**, for they were afraid of the presence of the Chaldeans. (LEB)

And again the NAC:

> Gedaliah does not rule long, for a group of men led by a certain
> Ishmael kills him. The reason for this murder is not altogether clear.
> It may be that this man of royal blood wants to claim power for
> himself. Jeremiah 40:13–14 states that the king of Ammon encourages
> Ishmael to kill Gedaliah, so regional rivalry contributes to this
> action. Either of these possible motives is equally foolish, since it
> is impossible to displace or even to bother Babylon at this time. Many
> of those still left in Jerusalem flee in fear to Egypt. Jeremiah says
> this flight is unnecessary, but in response the people force him to go
> with them (cf. Jer 42–43). Obviously, their tendency to ignore
> prophets and make poor political decisions does not end with the
> city’s destruction. Now Jerusalem has no one to tend to its future.
> Babylon’s grip on the city and region has only been strengthened by
> this episode.
> House, P. R. (1995). 1, 2 Kings (Vol. 8, pp. 399–400). Nashville: Broadman & Holman Publishers.

Comment: Very thorough, excellent answer. Thanks for contributing this! (+1)